# How to use Global Variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

How can i take global variables in jQuery.
this syntax is right that I'm using.

```
var $val = 2;
      or
val = 2; (without using var keyword).
```

Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: Avoid using global variables whenever possible. It is *(almost)* always possible. *(With apologies to the Dalai Lama)*

But answering the question:

If you use `var` at global scope (outside of all functions), it creates a global variable.

If you just assign to a variable you haven't declared anywhere, if you're not using strict mode (and I recommend you do use it), it will create a global implicitly. This is [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and should be avoided.

If you really, really need to create a global variable without using `var` at global scope, you can do that without the Horror by explicitly using the `window` object:

```
window.val = 2;
```

But I reiterate my opening point: Avoid globals.

Here's one way to do that: Use a scoping function around all of your code:

```
(function() { // <== The start of the scoping function
    // Your code here, `var`s here are global to *your* code but not actually globals
    // ...
})();         // <== The end of the scoping function, and the () to call it immediately
```

You should avoid globals even *within* your code, but by using a scoping function, you at least protect yourself from the outside world (and vice-versa).